# InvariantCulture ToString on an Object that Overloads ToString with Culture

Tags: c#

Here is my issue, my machine uses the French culture so by default it parses in the french way (3,141592).

Here is code that reproduces my problem if the machine culture is not US:

```
    float number = 4103.2680894812f;
    Object numObj = number;
    double val = Double.Parse(numObj.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    System.Console.WriteLine(val.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

At a glance this looks like it should work, but Float ToString is overloaded and uses culture so this actually does not work.

The problem is what is returned to me in practice is just an object because it could be a String a Float a Double or an Int.

A temporary solution is to use GetType() and check but I would like to know if a cleaner solution is possible.

Comment: You just parse as a double and hope? Even though you don't what it is? You could try casting to IFormattable and pass the Invariant culture in the ToString() overload

Comment: instead of parsing,can you use `Convert.ToDouble` ?

Comment: Why writing `numObj.ToString()` instead of `numObj.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`? You can only do something like `ToString()` (= deals with the default culture in the given context) when being completely sure that there is no problem with the culture. Otherwise, you would have to take care of this issue either by using the overload taking the culture/format as argument or by re-defining the culture in the given context (e.g., for that thread) before calling `ToString()`.

Comment: @varocarbas did you try numObj.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ... it does not exist.

Comment: No, I didn't try it, but it was a generic recommendation. The intention was transmiting an idea rather a specific solution. You might do something like `((float)numObj).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` or change the culture in the thread or even try another alternative. The whole point of my comment was that just `ToString()` doesn't offer any kind of control on the culture being accounted for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrenCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
try
{
    string s = numObj.ToString();
}
finally
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
}
```

Alternatively, use this:

```
string s;
var formattable = numObj as IFormattable;
if (formattable != null)
{
    s = formattable.ToString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
else
{
    s = numObj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Milo or [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) - I did get the two mixed up. Well spotted.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the suggested answer, you can remove the `InvariantCulture` from how you're parsing it, which works as well.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
float number = 4103.2680894812f;
Object numObj = number;
double val = Double.Parse(numObj.ToString());
System.Console.WriteLine(val.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Outputs 4103.268

Comment: Sure, but it looks like the question really is about the ToString method, and the parsing is just to illustrate the problem.